# Structuring backend queries

Tags: ios, node.js, sqlite, backend

So this is more of a methodology question than a coding question.  I want to ask this before I actually start coding in order to choose the best route.  I have a messaging app. When the app launches I query in the background all the messages from the backend where current_user_id is equal to recipient_id.  Now I have all of the messages stored the user needs to see so I locally store them into a sqlite database.

Great, but what about when the user gets new messages?  How can i structure a query to receive those without having to query the entire table again?  Also how do I set this up as a continual process?  Is the phone always requesting update information from the backend while its in the foreground?

Thanks. I really appreciate your help.  I'm currently using iOS and as stated SQLite.  Also my backend is AWS node.js.

Comment: If this is a real-time messaging app, you're going to want some sort of socket connection (at least while the app is open) rather than polling. As for checking if you have the latest messages, perhaps saving the timestamp of the latest message and only query newer messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your goal is to ultimately synchronize data between two sources over a network with a constraint that the client is updated in a reasonable amount of time.  You have a design choice to make between a [push vs pull architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402090/server-push-vs-client-pull-for-agent-server-topology).

Push architectures have the servers push data to clients when an event occurs.

Pull architectures have the device periodically poll the server for changes.  This can be achieved through timed events.

There are hybrid approaches too.

Each have their advantages and disadvantages as some require constant polling.  Others require constant connection based protocols which presents more scaling challenges.